# Will an automated scp script share files between Pis without Passwords?

Tags: python, networking, scp

I am planning on sending some files within an **Ad-Hoc** network of Pis.

#### Build

**Raspberry Pi - 2 Model B**

**Debian Wheezy 7.10/7.11**

I am planning to run a `cron` job between the Pis in vicinity. Through some applications which I have developed I retrieve my nearest / best neighbor and I would send my file via [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) which is a **SSH and SCP** module in Python.

I have shared the **SSH Key** with only my laptop, hence I can easily send/receive data without entering the Password with the Pis. But is not the case between each Pis.

So if I run a python script with *Paramiko* to `scp` my file on one of the Pi I *might* be asked the password.

Is there a way to by-pass this password authentication without having to share a common `ssh-key` with each Pis?

#### Note

the neighbor which I retrieve can keep changing, hence if I share my key with one Pi and if that Pi is not available the next time, I might have to send this file to the new neighbor which may not have the key.

Comment: Yes. If you set up your keys.

Comment: Can you please elaborate I am not sure which keys you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Using ssh keys will be the easiest method to do what you want to do with your Pi's

You can do this through SSH keys which will allow you to send files to other computers without a password. On the computer that you will send information from, use the command `ssh-keygen`. You can read more about that [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys). Then you can use the command `ssh-copyid username@remote-server` to share the keys. Finally you will have to edit your sshd config files to use passwordless ssh. More information on that [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).